# Create an Entity-Relationship Diagram from an XML Document

Tags: xml, database, entity-relationship, erd

I really don't know much about XML documents at all. But I was wondering if it is possible to generate an entity-relationship diagram from an XML document that details tables and primary keys within a database. For example:

```
<table name="journals">
    <field name="journal_id" type="I8">
        <KEY />
        <AUTOINCREMENT/>
    </field>
    <field name="path" type="C2" size="32">
        <NOTNULL/>
    </field>
    <field name="seq" type="F">
        <NOTNULL/>
        <DEFAULT VALUE="0"/>
    </field>
    <field name="primary_locale" type="C2" size="5">
        <NOTNULL/>
    </field>
    <field name="enabled" type="I1">
        <NOTNULL/>
        <DEFAULT VALUE="1"/>
    </field>
    <descr>Journals and basic journal settings.</descr>
    <index name="journals_path">
        <col>path</col>
        <UNIQUE />
    </index>
</table>
```

Is this at all possible and if so, what tool would be able to do it?

Thanks a lot,
Amy

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use XSLT to transform the <table> element to an SQL DDL statement, and then use a reverse engieering tool in e.g. Toad to create the diagram. However, the field (column) types looks funny.